# how to start already installed drupal page on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, drupal-7, localhost

I need a little help with my problem. I have to work with site which runs Drupal. I was given to my dropbox whole drupal project which was already installed, so it already has database and so on. I thought everything I need is to copy whole project into my root directory in var/www/, but of course I was wrong.On the internet I have just found tutorials for creating new Drupal projects and installing, but I haven't found how to start Drupal page, which is already installed. Could anyone help me. Few steps, what I need to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a Drupal installation from scratch as per the tutorials, then copying in the data from your existing SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

To move a website onto your local host there are 2 things you need. You need the website and you need the database. You can place the website in your var/www directory but then you need to  copy sites/default/default.settings.php to sites/default/settings.php and got into the settings.php and fill in the database info. The database info should look something like this:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'drupal_project',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'host' => 'localhost',
);
```

This will be pointing to your local installation of mysql where you will set up a database. You need to import the database from the old website into this database and once you have done those steps it should light right up. If you get errors past that make sure that your local server is set up properly https://www.drupal.org/requirements.